# Is require '/home/../http/' as fast as require '/http/'?

Tags: php, path, include, relative-path, absolute-path

I know that it is poor performance to use relative paths when including a file in php. But, is this true for for all paths or just paths relative to the assumed (context) include path?

Is this line

```
require '/home/../http/test.php'
```

as fast as this line

```
require '/http/test.php'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically yes. These paths are basically resolved first by php/apache then operating system.

Answer (score 4):

Either ways, an organized structure far out-weighs the small penalty spent on parsing a longer string.